# Disable linux internal route?

Tags: linux, networking, ping, nic

I have a system with 2 NIC(eth0,eth1),I connect them externally with a cable 
(use corssover cable or connect them to a same switch).
I want to ping eth1 ip address from eth0 and I want to traffic pass externally (through cable) from eth0 to eth1, but linux kernel send the traffic internally and don't allow it to pass over cable, 
How can I fix this and send traffic externally?
I use ping with "-I eth0" but the problem exists.

Comment: @hek2mgl with your rep, I hope you also submitted a close vote and not just make a trivial title edit.

Comment: @Alnitak I think the question is interesting but you are right, it is better suited for serverfault.com. Probably one can find the answer even on Google? :) I've never searched for this ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the VRF but with loopback which is used whenever kernel detects it can use it instead sending through the wire.

Let's use real MAC addresses and **dummy IP** addresses and NAT to force kernel to send data through wire:

```
arp -s IP0 MAC0
arp -s IP1 MAC1
ip route add IP0 dev eth1
ip route add IP1 dev eth0
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d IP1 -j SNAT --to-source IP0
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d IP0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d IP0 -j DNAT --to-destination IP0
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d IP1 -j DNAT --to-destination IP1
```

Answer (score -1):

First, enslave at least one of the interfaces on different VRF then try `ping -l eth0 dest`

Some helpful resources about VRF on Linux:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/vrf.txt

https://renard.chezwam.org/blog/2014/09/vrf-on-linux/index.html

PS: it is much simpler on BSD(rdomain) :)